# Usual infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

A definition of the sum of a family ${ a_i}$ of non negative numbers over an arbitrary index $I$ is like follows:

$$
\sum_{i \in I}^{} a_i = \sup \left\{\sum_{i \in A}^{} a_i \mid A \text{ finite}, A \subset I \right\} \in \left [ 0, \infty  \right ]$$

Then it says:

If $I$ is countably infinite and enumerated as $\left \{ i_0, i_1, i_2, ... \right \}$ then the above defined sum satisfies

a) $\sum_{i \in I}^{} a_i = \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty}{a_i}_{k}$,

provided that the value $\infty$ is allowed for the sum of series.

1. When it says that the value $\infty$ is allowed for the sum of series, does it mean that the sum includes the extended real numbers?
2. In equality $a)$, is the second term the usual infinite series?  I mean $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_m = \lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}s_m $, where $s_m$ is the sequence of partial sums

Comment: 1. It means the series doesn't converge. 2. yes.

Comment: The clue for 1 is where it says the $\sup$ in the general definition belongs to $[0, \infty]$ - a closed interval in the extended reals.

Comment: @Rob Arthan I've never worked with extended reals. I the sup is equal to the extended real $\infty$, does it mean that series diverges? Like in the non-extended reals.

Comment: Yes, to say a sum of non-negative is $\infty$ is equivalent to saying the sum diverges.